# trying to compile letters, numbers, and symbols into a rotating string

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

so, i am trying to have a repeating console.log that changes the digits to show every possible combination in any number of digits.
I have made a set of variables that define the digits I want to use and tried to make a function that uses letter arrays "console.log(s[0])" to use each character in the string. But whenever I try to run the code, it logs b to the console once and stops.
The code:

```
            function start()
            {
                var inputDigit = document.getElementById("inputDigit").value;
                var lowerCaseAlpabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                var upperCaseAlpabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                var symbols = "*&^%$#@!()<>?/.,|}{][-_=+~`"
                var Numbers = "1234567890"
                var all = lowerCaseAlpabet+upperCaseAlpabet+symbols+Numbers
                console.log(all)
                var allLength = all.length - 1


                var digit = 0
                digit1(all,allLength,digit)
                function digit1(all,allLength,zero){

                    if (digit < allLength) {
                            var finalValue = all[digit]
                            var digit = digit + 1
                            return finalValue
                        } 
                    return finalValue
                    var digit = digit + 1
                    console.log(finalValue)
                    digit1(all,allLength,digit)
                }



            }
```

The entire code document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>-->
    <title>Passcode Compiler</title>
    <h1>Welcome to the Passcode Compiler</h1>
    <h2>Please fill in the blank below with the amount of digits that you need</h2>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script>

    </script>
    <br> <input type="text" id="inputDigit">compiling length</input><br><!--This takes the year input-->
    <button onclick="start()">Submit</button><br><!--This submits the input values above to the javascript code below-->
    <script>


    function start()
    {
    var inputDigit = document.getElementById("inputDigit").value;
    var lowerCaseAlpabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var upperCaseAlpabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var symbols = "*&^%$#@!()<>?/.,|}{][-_=+~`"
    var Numbers = "1234567890"
    var all = lowerCaseAlpabet+upperCaseAlpabet+symbols+Numbers
    console.log(all)
    var allLength = all.length - 1


    var digit = 0
    digit1(all,allLength,digit)
    function digit1(all,allLength,zero){

    if (digit < allLength) {
    var finalValue = all[digit]
    var digit = digit + 1
    return finalValue
    } 
    return finalValue
    var digit = digit + 1
    console.log(finalValue)
    digit1(all,allLength,digit)
    }



    }

    </script>
    <h4>

    </h4> 
    </body>
    </html>
    </!doctype>
    <!--setTimeout(function(){/*YourCode*/},1000);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
keep in mind, i havent made the input important, so it should work regardless of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code following a return will not execute:

```
return finalValue
var digit = digit + 1
console.log(finalValue)
digit1(all,allLength,digit)
```

In this snippet, none of the lines after the return will execute since a function exits when it encounters a return statement.

Also, if you want to increment digit that is defined outside of your function you cannot declare it again as a `var` inside it. So, you will want to change your line

`var digit = digit + 1;`

to

`digit++;`

So I would start with adjusting your code to take these into consideration.